# Table stays empty PHP POO MVC

Tags: php, model-view-controller

I'm a dev web newbie and i'm so grateful you're reading this !
So my view which is supposed to display in a table the meetings that a registered user selected... well it remains empty. The code shows no errors (even without the require(s)) and my variables are okay (thanks var_dump) so I guess the link is broken between them and the ...displaying?

Here is the view :

```
<?php
$title="Shop : Mes rendez-vous";
 var_dump($_SESSION);
 var_dump($idUtilisateur);
ob_start();?>
<h1 class="m-3 text-white" style="text-shadow: 3px 3px black ;">Mes Rendez-vous</h1>
<div  style="background-color: #f5f5f5;" class="container">
<table class="table mb-5">
        <theader>
            <tr class="align-middle">
                <th class="liste-table">Début de la visite</th>
                <th class="liste-table">Fin de la visite</th>
                
            </tr>
        </theader>
        <tbody>
            <?php foreach ($lesVisites as $visite) { ?>
                <tr class=" align-middle">
                    <td class="liste-td"><?= $visite->getDebut() ?></td>
                    <td class="liste-td"><?= $visite->getFin() ?></td>
                </tr>
            <?php } ?>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
<?php
$content= ob_get_clean();
require("view/template.php");
?>
```

The function in the manager :

```
    {
        try{
        $connex=$this->lePDO;
        $sql=$connex->prepare("SELECT * FROM visite where idUtilisateur=:idUtilisateur");
        $sql->bindParam(":idUtilisateur",$idUtilisateur);
        $sql->execute();
        $sql->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_CLASS,"Visite");
        $resultat=$sql->fetch();
        return $resultat;
    }
    catch(PDOException $e)
    {
        echo $e->getMessage();
    }
    }
```

and the controller :

```
<?php

$action=filter_var($_GET["action"]??"utilisateur",FILTER_SANITIZE_FULL_SPECIAL_CHARS);

switch ($action){

    case "pageUtilisateur":
        $role=$_SESSION["role"]??false;
        if($role=="utilisateur"){
        $idUtilisateur=filter_var($_SESSION['id'], FILTER_SANITIZE_FULL_SPECIAL_CHARS);
        $objetVisiteManager=new VisiteManager($lePDO);
        $lesVisites=$objetVisiteManager->fetchAllVisiteByIdUtilisateur($idUtilisateur);
        
        require("view\utilisateurs\pageUtilisateur.php");
        }
        else{
        require "view/404.php";
        }
        break;

}

?>
```

the var_dump of $_SESSION and $idUtilisateur :

```
C:\wamp64\www\projetImmo\view\utilisateurs\pageUtilisateur.php:3:
array (size=3)
  'email' => string 'charliechaplin@gmail.com' (length=24)
  'id' => string '14' (length=2)
  'role' => string 'utilisateur' (length=11)

C:\wamp64\www\projetImmo\view\utilisateurs\pageUtilisateur.php:4:string '14' (length=2)
```

My Data base is fine.
Only an empty table is displayed. Can you help me? Thank you !

Answer (score 0):

ANSWER :

```
$resultat=$sql->fetchAll();
```

and not :

```
$resultat=$sql->fetch();
```